# Need to add a post’s featured image to a section on the frontpage

Tags: php, post-thumbnails, featured-post

It looks like I will need to create custom PHP code for this and either add it to my includes directory within a custom PHP file, or to the functions.php file.

I need the ability to use a featured image in a post and be able to also dynamically display that same image in a gallery on the frontpage.

I am not a PHP master by any means, but I know a bit to get around.

My guess is I would need something comparable to this:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {     
    echo '<div style='background-image: url(' . get_the_post_thumbnail_url() . ');></div>';
}
?>
```

How would I get the featured image to display within in a certain section on the frontpage?
Would I need to create a custom class to place this in a specific section on the frontpage?

There’s a “Projects” custom post type where the actual posts are created. There are fields within this post type created using ACF. There’s a “Project Featured” section in this custom post type that offers a toggle to turn off or on “Featured”. If the toggle is on, that is when the featured image should be used and displayed on the frontpage.

Thanks

Comment: Create a loop using [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) class. You should make use of the `meta_query` parameter to display those featured projects.

Comment: Care to give an example?

Comment: Check the link in my first comment.

Comment: I am already using WP_Query and it's working kinda, but I need to have the featured images placed in a certain area on the front page. How do I go about that? Thanks